# How do I check required fields on multiple forms on a single page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, css

I have a page that contains the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>

        <form action="demo_form.asp">
          Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
        </form>

        <div class="map"></div>
        <div><p>Some content to explain some things</p></div

        <form action="demo_form.asp">
          Username: <input type="text" name="lastusrname" required>
          <input type="submit">
        </form>

        <p><strong>Note:</strong> The required attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

When you click SUBMIT, it only checks the 2nd form where the input submit is included. I assume I will need to write some JQuery or Javascript function to check if all the required fields are filled out?

The reason for two forms is that I have other html between the forms

Comment: Why do you specifically need to have two forms here? If your just going to have a map in between it can reside inside of the form tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The reason for two forms is that I have other html between the forms

You *can* embed other HTML within a form - try it.  The existence of two `FORM` elements is what's breaking your form submission.

Comment: I know it might be the correct way to redesign the form, but I would rather not. The above is an example. I have over 1000 lines of code intermixed with the forms. Is there way to achieve this without altering the structure of the HTML?

Comment: This appears to be classic ASP.  Consider making make the stuff in-between the opening and closing `FORM` tags into an `#INCLUDE`.

Comment: I just removed all the other opening form and closing form tags between the first and last ending tag and it worked, without disrupting the look or structure of the content. MUCH THANKS!